# Password guessing program issue

Tags: python

I started programming very recently and I am trying to create a simple program that asks you to guess a password. You have max of 3 attempts and if you can't guess the password you have been denied access. (I originally saw similar program in wikibooks but I wanted to make my own). So here is my code:

```
  # Write a password guessing program to keep track of how many times the 
  # user has entered the password wrong.
  # If it is more than 3 times, print You have been denied access and 
  # terminate the program.
  # If the password is correct, print You have successfully logged in and 
  # terminate the program.

  guess_count = 0

  correct_pass = 'password'

  pass_guess = str(input("Please enter your password: "))
  guess_count += 1

  while True:
      if pass_guess == correct_pass:
          guess_count += 1
          print('You have successfully logged in.')
          break

      elif pass_guess != correct_pass:
          if guess_count < 3:
              guess_count += 1
              str(input("Wrong password. Try again. "))
          elif guess_count >= 3:
              print("You have been denied access.")
              break
```

As I said I am very new to programming and don't understand loops very well. The code works only if I write correct password on first attempt and it also works if all of my 3 attemps are wrong. Other than that, it does not work. What did I do wrong?

Comment: you need to put `pass_guess = str(input('...'))` inside your `while` loop

Comment: Don't use `elif` when the second condition is the exact opposite of the first condition. Just use `else:`

Answer (score 0):

When you ask the user to try again, you don't update the `pass_guess` variable. They type a new password but the program continues to test the first guess. Change

```
str(input("Wrong password. Try again. "))
```

to:

```
pass_guess = str(input("Wrong password. Try again. "))
```

You also don't need to use `str()` when you call `input()`, since it always returns a string (I assume you're using Python 3.x -- if you're using 2.x you should be using `raw_input()` instead of `input()`).